# Why is git downloading folders as files?

Tags: git, openshift, git-clone

For some reason, when I clone a repository on my openshift gear some directories show as the name of the directory, but they are files without extensions. How can I fix this?

Comment: "some directories show as the name of the directory, but they are files without extensions" what? and how is openshift related?

Comment: @eis I should have mentioned the server is on openshift. I doubt it matters, but I thought I would include it. Updated. As for the what, I'm not to sure either. On the server, for example, there is a directory, and when I clone the repository, it shows up as a file.

Comment: I guess you are on Windows and the "directories" in the repository are actually symbolic links?

Comment: @xuhdev I never thought of that. I checked and your right, they are symlinks. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> some directories show as the name of the directory, but they are files without extensions

In your case the "folders" are links.
They can be **symbolic links** or **submodules**.

---

### ***`Example:`***

This is how submodules appear in github:

[image]

When checked out to git they are simple folders

---

And this is how **symlinks** are displayed (arrow)

[image]

And on the file system (Unix) it will look lie this:

[image]

Comment: `shFlags` is a submodule. A symbolic link on GitHub looks like a document icon with a curved arrow.

Comment: Agree. im still trying to find out a repo with a symbolic link :-)

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the fact that the directories in the repo are actually symbolic links to directories and you are on Windows. If this is the case, you can simply ignore it, and use the actual path to the directory when dealing with files in them.